# wcf service method caching not working

Tags: c#, wcf, caching

I am trying to implement caching in WCF service. Please find the below code.

Contract :

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
    [OperationContract]
    int GetNumber();
```

Contract implementation :

```
   [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)] 
   public class Service1 : IService1
   {    
[AspNetCacheProfile("MoviesCollection")]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
    public int GetNumber()
    {
        Random number = new Random();
        return number.Next(1, 899);
    }
  }
```

Web.Config

```
<caching>
  <outputCache enableOutputCache="true"/>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="MoviesCollection" location="Server" duration="6000" varyByParam="none"
       enabled="true"/>
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

I am using WCF service application and not WCF service library.
Please let me know what i am missing here. thanks.

Regards,
Jebli

Comment: Should we configure WCF service as REST service to enable caching ?

Comment: Take a look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745338/wcf-cache-not-working/25760949

Answer (score 0):

"To enable WEB HTTP service caching you must first enable ASP.NET compatibility "
Check this link from  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

Comment: I have tried to implement whatever mentioned on that link but that does not work. Any help would be apprecated. thanks.