# WCF Cache Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, caching

I want to cache some services in my WCF Service. I used Microsoft [Caching Support for WCF Web HTTP Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443(v=vs.110).aspx) as my reference. My server web.config file is:

```
  <caching>
    <outputCache enableOutputCache="true" />
    <outputCacheSettings>
      <outputCacheProfiles>
        <add name="GetCurrentDateTime" location="Server" duration="604800" varyByParam="offset; lang; categorytype" enabled="true" />
      </outputCacheProfiles>
    </outputCacheSettings>
  </caching>
```

And

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
        multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

My solution is like this (containing only 2 web projects.):

[image]

And my client code is (located in Default.aspx):

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new Test_Services.TestServicesClient();

        var dateTime = client.GetCurrentDateTime();
        Response.Write(dateTime);
    }
}
```

Service is:

```
    [WebGet]
    [AspNetCacheProfile("GetCurrentDateTime")]
    public string GetCurrentDateTime()
    {
        var datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        return datetime;
    }
```

Simply returns current date time. So I hope it return's constant date time for "604800 seconds" interval (as declared in web.config). But it will be updated every time client call it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure but [WebGetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) is for RESTful service. So I think the entire caching will be work only for RESTful services.

Another way for caching is described in http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/caching-in-wcf-services-part-1/.